# "Error! You do not have permission to access this page" After completing event signup

Tags: civievent, recurring-contributions

I am running CiviCRM 5.53.0 on WordPress 6.0.2.

It recently came to my attention that people signing up for an event are getting **"Error! You do not have permission to access this page"** after completing their signup.  I did a test and confirmed it is happening.  See screenshot.
[image]

I checked the Users and Permissions configs and all boxes are checked for **CiviCRM: access AJAX API** like they should be.

Does anyone know what I missing?

Comment: no idea, but may be worth comparing with the link you get to at https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ for a similar sign up. also, are people registering directly via the civi form or do you have this as a shortcode in WP?

Comment: The event page is a short code on a WordPress page, but not the form. This is the URL to the form. 
https://secure.oursite.org/2023-conference/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fregister&id=367&reset=1

Comment: If you install the Log Viewer Extension then you can take a look at the source of those error messages.